# ModuleNotFoundError despite declairing install_requires in setup.py

Tags: python, pandas, pip, package, setup.py

I wrote create a package uploaded to PyPI for testing, but I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` for pandas when I try to import it to a virtual environment. I import pandas in a file in the package and therefore, declared it in `setup.py` under `install_requires = ['pandas']`. Before that, I had a `setup.cfg` and declared it in `pyproject.toml\`

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=42",
    "pandas",
    "wheel"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

but neither worked. Am I declaring pandas at the wrong place? Are there some other files/folder-structure which I should share for solving this problem? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test PyPI is separate from PyPI, and does not have every dependency you try to download, which is why they aren't found. According to the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-testpypi/), you can use `--extra-index-url` to point to PyPI for dependencies.

Example:

```
python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ your-package
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it did actually work as soon as I uploaded it to the "real" PyPl. I have no clue why it wouldn't work for Test PyPl, if you do know, feel free to enlighten us in the comments, I'll update the answer.